# Does Antd Table have multiple custom selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, datatable, antd

I am using the Antd Table with the custom selection option that's demoed [here](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-row-selection-custom). 
I was able to get my code to work like the demo, where I click on one item from the dropdown menu and the respective table rows will be selected.

But I would like to be able to select multiple items from the dropdown menu and have all respective rows be selected in the table.

Can somebody please throw some light into this? Thanks very much!

Comment: any own attempt?

Comment: I was looking more towards any props that the Antd Table component allows to choose multiple, that may not have been documented perhaps? Anyway, I was able to write my triggers for these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to render a Checkbox component in place of each of the options listed in the dropdown, and use the onChange hook on checking/unchecking to trigger the rowSelection.